# Use a maven repo which does not have pom files

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

We have a large custom artifact repository which is used by our old internal ant builds.

It stores jars in much the same way that a maven repository does.  i.e.

```
http://repo/root/<group>/<artifact>/<version>/<artifact>-<version>.jar
```

But, this repository does_not_ contain pom files.  Just jars and src jars.

We are now migrating a whole lot of projects to using maven/gradle, these use an Artifactory installation that we have.  But the projects still have a lot of dependencies on artifacts stored in the old repository.

I was wondering if anyone knew a way of accessing this old style repo (which does not have poms) using maven/gradle?

We *could* synthesize and insert a whole lot of simple poms, which just have group/artifact/version etc, and no dependencies.  But was wondering if there might be a simpler way.

After all, the group/artifact/version is in the path itself.  The poms never contain dependencies, so in this situation the poms wouldn't (as far as I can see) provide any additional info.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle doesn't need pom files, if they aren't available it should just reference the jars directly. So this should "just work"

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo/root"
    }
}
```

If, for some reason, there's slight differences you could use the Ivy repository. See [custom ivy repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#sec:ivy_repositories) and [IvyArtifactRepository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.IvyArtifactRepository.html) Eg:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        url "http://repo/root" 
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We just had to ensure that our filenames follow the maven convention and it worked.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

When you transform the projects to Maven, you need to touch the dependency definitions. You need to to replace old, file-based accesses by Maven coordinates.

Therefore, I would suggest the following (we did something very similar, only with a Windows network drive instead of a http based repository):

- Write a script that uploads all your artifacts from the old repository to your artifactory. If you use maven `deploy:deploy-file`, Maven will create stub poms for you.
- Write scripts for the developers that translate the references on the old repository by the respective Maven coordinates for the pom.

As a side note: In our company, the old "repository" and the Maven repository were actively used (and written to) at the same time, so we developed a two-way synchronisation job between our Nexus and the old "repository".